# d3 tree: specify minimum distance between nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tree, force-layout

I made a tree diagram in d3 using this example as a base:
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

However, instead of normalizing the y-coordinates based on depth, I instead calculated the y-coordinates based on the weight of each node:

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = (maximumWieght - d.wieght + 1) * 20; 
    });
```

This way, nodes of equal weight are at the same level of the graph, regardless of their actual depth.

This causes an issue, however, as many nodes forced to the same level of the graph are now overlapping. Thus, I need to specify a minimum distance. There are several ways I've tried to approach this:

I first discovered that d3 has internal parameters for the size of the tree and the separation of nodes (as described in source 1). Therefore, I tried specifying the size of the tree this way:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([reallyBigNumber, viewerWidth]);
```

and, for good measure, I imparted the same dimensions to the SVG itself:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", viewerWidth)
.attr("height", reallyBigNumber)
```

This is actually the solution to my problem according to source 2. However, the result was not favorable. Although the SVG became very large on the page, the tree itself did not change size at all. It remained the same size and left a lot of empty space.

So then I tried specifying the separation this way:

```
function separate() {
    tree.separation(function(a, b) {
        return a.weight - b.weight < 5 ? moderatelyBigNumber : 2;
    });
}
```

This did not work for multiple reasons: first of all, it only specified distance between immediate siblings. This is useless because I'm dealing with overlapping nodes which have the same weight, but are not necessarily siblings at all. Secondly, when I made the separation larger it did not actually increase the distance between the specified nodes. Instead, it decreased the distance between the rest of the nodes by the same proportion. Although this is an underhanded way of doing what I told the nodes to do, it is ultimately the exact opposite of what I wanted.

Further thoughts:

I could calculate the x-value just as I did for the y. However, that gets really complicated really fast, and trying to reinvent d3's wheel could easily create more bugs.

I could implement forces on the node that force them to separate, similar to source 3. However, I cannot seem to find a straight-forward way of implementing a force layout on a tree diagram.

I could redo the entire tree as a phylogram, which would allow for variable branch lengths, as seen in source 4. However, I cannot find any way of implementing the same features on a phylogram as on a tree diagram (such as collapsing nodes or dynamic styling), and documentation on phylograms relative to trees is very scarce.

Thus, if anyone of you could either solve one of the above attempted solutions, or propose a better solution I haven't thought of, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sources:
1) https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout
2) http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/09/15/render-a-d3-tree-with-a-minimum-distance-between-the-tree-nodes/
3) http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729
4) http://bl.ocks.org/kueda/1036776

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle.net?!